# Count the number of times a pair of value occurs in a Dartaframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(df)

Product      Store    Quantity_Sold
   A          NORTH          10
   A          NORTH          5
   A          SOUTH          8

   B          SOUTH          8
   B          SOUTH          5

(...)
```

I would like to count the number of times the same pair of product and store is present; to illustrate:

```
print(final_df)

Product      Store       count
   A          NORTH        2
   A          SOUTH        1

   B          SOUTH        2

(...)
```

I tried with:

```
df["Product"].value_counts()
```

But it only works with single columns. How can I create final_df?

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index='Product', columns='Store', aggfunc='count')`